# Oracle COUNT(DISTINCT expr) causes ORA-00979 error

Tags: oracle, ora-00979

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
   t.f1
   , COUNT(DISTINCT t.f2) AS distinct_count
FROM
   some_table t
GROUP BY
   t.f1
```

which works fine.
However, if I attempt to do this, it gives me a `ORA-00979 not a GROUP BY expression` error.

```
WITH my_aggregate_data AS
(
   SELECT
      t.f1
      , COUNT(DISTINCT t.f2) AS distinct_count
   FROM
      some_table t
   GROUP BY
      t.f1
)

SELECT
   *
FROM
   ( SELECT f1, distinct_count FROM my_aggregate_data )
PIVOT
   (
      SUM(distinct_count)
      FOR f1
      IN (a, b, c)
   )
```

If I simply remove the `DISTINCT` key word from the `COUNT` method, it works fine (except that the count is a total count and not a distinct count).

This seems like a fairly straight forward query, but I have been unable to locate anyone else documenting this issue (which probably means I'm doing something wrong).

I also found nothing in the Oracle documentation that indicates that `COUNT(DISTINCT exp)` would behave differently than `COUNT(exp)` other than the obvious distinction between the two.

I have also written it this way

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         t.f1
         , COUNT(DISTINCT t.f2) AS distinct_count
      FROM
         some_table t
      GROUP BY
         t.f1
   )
PIVOT
   (
      SUM(distinct_count)
      FOR f1
      IN (a, b, c)
   )
```

but it just results in the same ORA-00979 error, and again, if you remove the `DISTINCT` key word, everything works (except that it gives me the wrong answer).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your sample data and the actual query, so cannot say for sure why ORA-00979 is raised. But, as far as the query you posted is concerned, the problem is in your `PIVOT` expression and nothing else.

```
IN (a, b, c)
```

This throws the error

> ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot
>   values

which means the values specified in the `IN` clause of `PIVOT` should be constants (string literals/ numbers etc)

If you use

```
IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

It works perfectly fine.

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b96730a1bd13fbc2fc6bccd846beb85e) to see both the error message and working query.